# Why do I get undefined method `action' for PostsController(Table doesn't exist)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am pretty new to coding, so I decided to start the Ruby on Rails guide for version 4.0.0 and have had problem after problem. I am currently running version 4.0.0 and I have followed the guide step by step.

Once I got to 5.2 First form I began to get errors and was using other people's posts to solve my questions, but this error doesn't seem to happen for anyone else, so here it is:

```
NoMethodError in PostsController#index
undefined method `action' for PostsController(Table doesn't exist):Class
```

Here is my code:

```
class PostsController < ActiveRecord::Base                             

attr_accessible :title, :text                            

  def new                                                              
  end                                                                  

  def create                                                           
    @post = Post.new(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))              

    @post.save                                                         
    redirect_to @post                                                  
  end                                                                  

  def show                                                             
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])                                     
  end                                                                  

  def index                                                            
    @post = Post.all                                                   
  end                                                                  

  def action                                                           
  end                                                                  

  private                                                              
    def post_params                                                    
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)                      
    end                                                                

end
```

Here is my view:

```
<p>
  <strong> Title: </strong>
  <%= @post.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong> Text: </strong>
  <%= @post.text %>
</p>
```

My form is:

```
<h1> New Post </h1>

 <%= form_for :posts, url: posts_path do |f| %>

  <p>
   <%= f.label :title %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text%><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
   <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
  <% end %>
```

The error states that I don't have an action method defined, but I'm not sure how to define one in the first place, however this is not all. When I go to my localhost:3000/posts/new page I get the same error but for    `PostsController#new`

Can someone please help me!!

Comment: `Table doesn't exist` should be a good clue. Does that table exist in your database?

Comment: I looked in the database and i don't seem to have a table in there, do you have any advice as to how i can put one in there or what i need to do to get one?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's not clear why your controller is inheriting from a model class:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  # ...
end
```

Comment: The reason i am inheriting from a model class is because attr_accessible does not work without ActiveRecord::Base being inherited. without attr_accessible there seemes to be a problem calling on title and text for my form.

Comment: Actually i just realized that i had to put attr_accessible in the actual Ative Record Base and change that controller back to ApplicationController!! thank you for the help.

Comment: ActiveRecord is for models only. Putting that declaration in the model like you have done is the correct way to do it.